# Why Admob Test Ads & Real Ads are not loading after changing the App Signing Key in Google Play Cons.?

Tags: android, admob, ads, google-play-console, android-app-signing

I've recently changed my lost app signing key via Google Play Console (through Play Console App Integrity support) and it was successful. Now, I can upload my app having the same package id by signing with the new updated key.

But after this change, Admob test and real ads both are not loading and showing error in logcat like **"Error 3: Ad failed to load".**

What I've already tested but didn't work:

- Tried to load the test ads using test ad units.
- Tried to load test ads by adding test devices as suggested in the logcat.
- Added app-ads.txt for testing as well.
- Same code implementation works perfectly in other app.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is very unique case, so I suggest contacting AdMob support, if you could not get help from them, you can do the following as a last resort:

You can delete the app from AdMob then add it again, which will give you a new App id, then create new Ad units and reflect new ids in your App.

Comment: Admob doesn't allow app deletion. Only Ad units can be deleted and re-created. But test ad units are also not loading test ads.